# How to get value inside value from Json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to retrieve json values inside values through JS.
this is my code :

```
var out_show = null;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://milnomedia.net/menudoc.js',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

        var div_data='';
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            div_data +="<div><a href=''>"+data.menu.sub.menu[index].name+"</a></div>";
        });


        $('.doc-menu-one').html(div_data);

        out_show = div_data;
    }
});

$('.doc-menu-one').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.doc-menu-one').fadeIn(400);
    });

     var code = $('.doc-menu-one').html(out_show);

})
```

What exactly I want. can you see in second part "name":Documentry.
I want to read from that part and get sub, menu values.

can you please tell me how to get these values.
appreciate your time and comments.
thank you very much!

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. Can you validate here http://jsonlint.com/ and correct it

Comment: Hi there,
I just changed the code and now you can try it
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be help .

```
   $(data).each(function(e,v){
        $(v.menu).each(function(index, element) {
           // console.log(element);
            $(element).each(function(f, element_value) {
                    console.log(element_value);
                    if(element_value.name == "Documentry")
                    {
                        $(element_value.sub.menu).each(function(a, element_menu_data) {

                            console.log(element_menu_data);

                            $(element_menu_data.cat).each(function(c, element_menu_cat_data) {

                                  console.log(element_menu_cat_data);
                            });
                        });
                    }
            });

        });
});
```

you have to first itrate the each loop of your data and then from each you have to itrate another each for your inside array in json

Comment: Confusing, can you please clarify me more

Comment: are you aware with each loop ?

Comment: Hi there,
I am little bit new to json
Thanks!

Comment: can you put your json response

Comment: try console log and see what you find , try it will definitely help

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://milnomedia.net/menudoc.js',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var div_data = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $.each(item, function (j,subitem) {
                    if (subitem.name == "Documentry") {
                        for (var k in subitem.sub.menu) {

                            div_data += "<div><a href=''>" + subitem.sub.menu[k].name + "</a></div>";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(div_data);
   }
});
```